# Invulnerability timer while standing on spikes

Tags: javascript, timer

I want to decrement the player's health every .7 seconds while the warrior is standing on a spike tile. Every frame, the game calculates what kind of tile the player is walking into. I've tried calling a function that uses `setTimeout` from the spike tile code in the `walkingIntoTileType` switch statement and I've tried using `setInterval` directly in the switch statement. My current implementation has this declaration at the top of the warrior class:

```
this.interval = setInterval(function() {
            //blank
        }, 1000);
clearInterval(this.interval);
```

I then have this in the warrior movement code, which gets run every frame:

```
switch( walkIntoTileType ) {
  case TILE_GROUND:
    this.x = nextX;
    this.y = nextY;
    this.onSpikes = false;
    break;
  //other tile type code...
  case TILE_SPIKES:
    this.x = nextX;
    this.y = nextY;
    this.onSpikes = true;
  default:
    // any other tile type number was found... do nothing, for now
    break;
}
if(this.onSpikes){
    if(!this.running){
        this.running = true;
        this.interval = setInterval(function() {
            this.playerHealth--;
        }, 700);
    }
}
else{
    this.running = false;
    clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Despite this, the player's health never gets decremented when on the spikes, and the console returns no errors. I would think the interval is not falling victim to garbage collection since its variable is declared at the top of the class, but obviously I could be wrong.

Comment: The inbuilt JavaScript timing functions aren't really designed for games. You will be better off if you do your own timekeeping in your game loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the last time the player tripped on a spike:

```
var spikeTimer = 0;
```

If the player stands on a spike and the difference between the current time and the spikeTimer's value is greater, than 700 ms, then damage the player, and set the timer to the current time:

```
if (Date.now() - spikeTimer >= 700) {
    spikeTimer = Date.now();
    // Damage the player
}
```